# Error using Windows CreateFilemapping

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-mapped-files

In my project I have implemented the `CreateFileMapping` concept to share memory between two processes. I have a server process in which I store the memory address of my session data, which contains details about a particular image. And I have a client process in which I read that address from the buffer. Now the problem is the address is shown in the client process but some details are missing.

This is my server process code:

```
HANDLE hMem;
LPCSTR  pBuf;
#define BUF_SIZE 1024
static const char MemoryName[]="Share Memory Name";

hMem=CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,NULL, PAGE_READWRITE,0, BUF_SIZE, MemoryName);
pBuf = (LPCSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMem, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, BUF_SIZE);
CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, session, BUF_SIZE); 
LtEntity test = LtEntity(pBuf);
```

This is my client process code:

```
HANDLE hMem;
LPCSTR  pBuf;
#define BUF_SIZE 1024
static const char MemoryName[]="Share Memory Name";

hMem = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, MemoryName);  
pBuf = (LPCSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMem, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, BUF_SIZE);                   
LtEntity test = LtEntity(pBuf);
```

In server process the variable "test" contains all the details but in the client "test" has some data missing.

The server test variable below shows the attached image which shows the contents of the variable.

The client test variable below shows the attached image which shows the contents of the variable.

Please do check the difference i need the item data also visible in my client process..

Answer (score 1):

> some details are missing

You can say that again. What is the definition of `LtEntity`?

Does the file mapping contain any embedded pointers? Those won't work, because the shared memory won't necessarily have the same virtual address in each process. And they won't work if they point outside the file mapping, even if the shared memory did happen to have the same virtual address in each process. Instead of pointers, you should store offsets from the beginning of the file mapping.

Are both processes running in the same login session? If not, you need to add the [`Global\` prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537(VS.85).aspx) to the name of the file mapping.

Also, you should use `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, not `(HANDLE)0xFFFFFFFFF`. The definition of `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` changed when 64-bit Windows was added.

You can use `LtEntity test(pBuf);` instead of `LtEntity test = LtEntity(pBuf);`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have pointers in LtEntity it won't work, as the mapped memory block in each process will typically start at a different address. Try using Boost::interprocess [offset pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_offset_ptr), which store relative addresses instead.

Comment: +1 for recommending Boost::interprocess. Don't fiddle with the low level error prone details if you can use a nice (well tested) abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have pointers/references in `LtEntity` which aren't serialized, too.

Perhaps you can give more information about `LtEntity` and which data is missing.